# How to exclude numbers in a range

Tags: python, python-3.x, range

I'm quite a beginner, so I'm sorry if this is really dumb.

```
for i in range(3, 5) + range(5, 7) + range(7, 9) + range(9, sheet.max_column):
```

I'm working with an excel spreadsheet, this being one of my lines of code, from which the issue is occurring. As you can tell, I am trying to exclude certain columns (4, 5 + 6, 7 + 8, 9) from interfering with each other. When running the program, I get this error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/pc/PycharmProjects/ExcelCalculator/Excel/Test.py", line 5, in <module>
    for i in range(3, 5) + range(5, 7) + range(7, 9) + range(9, sheet.max_column):
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'range' and 'range'
```

It's clear the "+" sign shouldn't be used, so what should be instead?

Comment: Seems odd - if you added your ranges youd still get `range(3, sheet.max_column)` ... there are no numbers "excluded" at all.

Comment: You can define a full range and exclude the ones you don't want with an if statement in the body. (i.e `if i in something: continue`)

Comment: Ah, okay. What would be in the if statement to loop it back? Would I use None or something?

Comment: `skip = frozenset( (3,7,92) )` - `for n in range(3,sheet.max_column): if n in skip: continue`

Comment: but still - your example _does not skip any number_

Comment: Okay, I think I found the problem, but can you please just tell me how to add the ranges?